# Lollipop: alarm isn't firing in time

Tags: nexus-5, alarm, 5.0-lollipop, clock, date-and-time

After updating my Nexus 5 to Android 5.0 I noticed that alarm is not fired at set time (actually that spoiled my today's morning).

When I set time for alarm it writes correct delta (e.g."Alarm set for 3 minutes from now"), but it doesn't make any sound or any on-screen changes in 3 minutes: the alarm just hangs in notification tray as an "Upcoming alarm".

I've checked the notification settings and didn't find any problem. but the notifications from Google Keep don't work as well...

What can be wrong with built-in alarm in Android L?

Comment: Did you turn on "Priority Mode" to "None" by any chance?

Comment: Nah, it was the first thing I checked :(

Comment: Did you ever find out the cause? I have the same issue with my Nexus 4

Comment: In the end I just factory reset. That did it :(

Comment: Some debugging I'd like to ask: did you have two factor authentication for your default Google account? I thought it might be the cause because I couldn't authenticate and I wasn't logged in.

Comment: Yes, I do have 2-factor auth connected. But I doubt it can be a root cause for this problem, because it's gone after hard reset and 2-factor auth is still connected and used.

Comment: Maybe but I noticed that I wasn't logged in after the update, because of two factor, and I couldn't authenticate anyway. I think the reasons the notifications weren't firing was because they were linked to my Google account. Have you upgraded to 5.01 yet?

Comment: Yep, I did. All systems nominal :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find the solution so I followed [Ian Clark's advice](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88777/lollipop-alarm-isnt-firing-in-time?noredirect=1#comment112085_88777) and performed factory reset. That helped.

Answer (score 1):

I went through and stopped all of the Google Play Services (Settings->Apps->Running), including the cached process(Settings->Apps->Running->Show cached processes). It takes persistence, since they restart sometimes, keep at it and kill them dead. Restart when you get them stopped.

I get text's again (these would previously show as "Downloading 1KB") and the alarms go off now.

Hope this helps someone else, or at the very least saves them the hassle of a factory reset.